# Why 0010 give different result in array in java

Tags: java, arrays

If I placed 00 or 0 before digits values in array output become different.

```
 int arr[][]=new int[3][2];
    arr[0][0]=00;
    arr[0][1]=01;
    arr[1][0]=10;
    arr[1][1]=0011;
    arr[2][0]=0020;
    arr[2][1]=21;
    for(int a[]: arr){
        for(int c : a){
            System.out.println(c);
        }

    }
```

Output is :
0
1
10
9
16
21

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: @RohitJain it looks like he may have been expecting `0, 1, 10, 11, 20, 21`

Comment: By putting a leading zero in front of the numbers you're turning them into **octal** literals.

Comment: I guess the OP's question is *why the input and output are different. Who is converting the octal numbers to decimal ?*. So, not sure if this should be marked as a duplicate. Re-opened it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A number with a leading zero is treated as [Octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

Your `0011` is octal `8 + 1 = 9`, `0020` is `2 * 8 = 16`.

Note that your `00` and `01` are also being interpreted in Octal but they just happen to be the same value as their decimal counterparts.

Answer (score 6):

Because you are *inserting numbers* in base-8 (*octal*) format (use of `0` at the beginning) and printing them using base-10 (*decimal*) using `Integer.toString(i, 10);`

`println()` converts all integers to base-10 and prints them.

Comment: Integer.toString(i, 10); only convert single index in array. how can i conver whole array(2-diementional)

Comment: @SyedaShah- You will have to call it on each element of 2-D array. No other option :)

Answer (score 5):

There is a literal prefix `0` which means octal number

`int decimal = 100;   // 100 represented in decimal base
 int octal = 0144;    // decimal 100 represented in octal base
 int hex = 0x64;      // decimal 100 represented in hexadecimal base
 int bin = 0b1100100; // decimal 100 represented in binary base`